# systemd[1]: Caught <SEGU>, dumped core as pid – core file replication issue

Tags: centos, pidfile

I'm having an issue with my CentOS VM server [CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)]

It will generate the error log as below randomly and cannot be stopped.

We did not change/touch anything inside the system before this issue happened.

Also, there will be a lot of core file (replication)
and it keeps replicating the files
until the space in the `/` directory is full,
resulting in the server hanging.

After we reboot the VM, we can see a lot of core files in the `/` directory before the server clean up the core files itself and repeats the cycle. (Core file replication -> server hang -> reboot --> core file self cleanup -> repeat)

```
[18618.7622431 systemd[1]: Caught <SEGU>, dumped core as pid 13797. 
[18618.7779581 systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

I try to debug the core file using GDB, but I am not an expert.

I need someone to help me solve this issue as this server is an LDAP server so it cannot be down or not available.

```
#eu-unstrip -n --core=./core.83771 
0x55b8183db000+0x388000 d77f0d899b2ea5f179296f1b24659b202edc082d@0x55b8183db2bc . /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/systemd/systemd.debug /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
0x7ffe5e165000+0x1000 049491c06a8b580d7e7ae0ec561a4a85e555def2@0x7ffe5e165328 . - linux-vdso.so.1
0x7f3eb718f000+0x204180 fb47c8b42bba8c045d274fff6c275d6e46c2140b@0x7f3eb718f210 /lib64/libuuid.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0.debug libuuid.so.1
0x7f3eb7394000+0x23fb88 130ad6a89bad9508721c9c65f05b6073aefab954@0x7f3eb7394210 /lib64/libblkid.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libblkid.so.1.1.0.debug libblkid.so.1
0x7f3eb75d4000+0x215068 8f3f245bd066e1a955da66a1546978dac0e2dce8@0x7f3eb75d41d8 /lib64/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7.debug libz.so.1
0x7f3eb77ea000+0x225288 f744796ea6fa4d8019414f5487ee85de74dc5adc@0x7f3eb77ea1d8 /lib64/liblzma.so.5 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2.debug liblzma.so.5
0x7f3eb7a10000+0x205180 43578677df613e9d58128ed4ae0c344fbc1e44c0@0x7f3eb7a10210 /lib64/libcap-ng.so.0 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libcap-ng.so.0.0.0.debug libcap-ng.so.0
0x7f3eb7c16000+0x204170 2617ecc6738047e207ae3add990bd6a34d11b265@0x7f3eb7c161d8 /lib64/libattr.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0.debug libattr.so.1
0x7f3eb7e1b000+0x261208 9ca3d11f018beeb719cdb34be800bf1641350d0a@0x7f3eb7e1b1d8 /lib64/libpcre.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0.debug libpcre.so.1
0x7f3eb807d000+0x203130 7f2e9cb0769d7e57bd669b485a74b537b63a57c4@0x7f3eb807d1d8 /lib64/libdl.so.2 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so.debug libdl.so.2
0x7f3eba34f000+0x223150 62c449974331341bb08dcce3859560a22af1e172@0x7f3eba34f1d8 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so.debug ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x7f3eb8281000+0x3cd200 9470e279388f7f9cb2ed3b2872d0c2095b191ff4@0x7f3eb8281280 /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so.debug libc.so.6
0x7f3eb864f000+0x21b488 e10cc8f2b932fc3daeda22f8dac5ebb969524e5b@0x7f3eb864f248 /lib64/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so.debug libpthread.so.0
0x7f3eb886b000+0x215400 edf51350c7f71496149d064aa8b1441f786df88a@0x7f3eb886b1d8 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1.debug libgcc_s.so.1
0x7f3eb8a81000+0x207c38 3e44df7055942478d052e40fdd1f5b7862b152b0@0x7f3eb8a811d8 /lib64/librt.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so.debug librt.so.1
0x7f3eb8c89000+0x242d80 2f1008b054be76260028b63c782bdfd3fc9fe667@0x7f3eb8c89210 /lib64/libmount.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libmount.so.1.1.0.debug libmount.so.1
0x7f3eb8ecc000+0x215370 a860e5cb34a8bf6cf7194d3385a676b513be991c@0x7f3eb8ecc1d8 /lib64/libkmod.so.2 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.2.10.debug libkmod.so.2
0x7f3eb90e2000+0x228388 2e36e1b9a2d92c969e38cddcc729f55d8bacbb2b@0x7f3eb90e21d8 /lib64/libaudit.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0.debug libaudit.so.1
0x7f3eb930b000+0x20e250 d908e2ffa0016fc4601c0de7c07f725c5d4c98d4@0x7f3eb930b1d8 /lib64/libpam.so.0 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1.debug libpam.so.0
0x7f3eb951a000+0x204240 3bc565e0565c33b1bd37ae0070f7d8e2ce4313e4@0x7f3eb951a1d8 /lib64/libcap.so.2 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libcap.so.2.22.debug libcap.so.2
0x7f3eb971f000+0x226970 903a0bd0bfb4fee8c284f41beb9773ded94cbc52@0x7f3eb971f210 /lib64/libselinux.so.1 /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1.debug libselinux.so.1
0x7f3eb9946000+0x201290 f2f4830be57dfbb423585ee79baf76a7914adbcf@0x7f3eb99461a0 /usr/local/lib/sshpkit.so - sshpkit.so
0x7f3eb9b48000+0x201290 0b827ba048d96d2c1df964f98afa4f582132d4d3@0x7f3eb9b481a0 /usr/local/lib/sshkit.so - sshkit.so
0x7f3eb9d4a000+0x201290 f03bbd443cebe3e835a76bbb536ed8838164feec@0x7f3eb9d4a1a0 /usr/local/lib/skit.so - skit.so
0x7f3eb9f4c000+0x200c70 77591fbdfb5ba55dc03a598a619694e4fa5d3b6e@0x7f3eb9f4c1a0 /usr/local/lib/fkit.so - fkit.so
0x7f3eba14d000+0x201290 35ed4d4750d3f80936d9ce2dd6d965bb8f527414@0x7f3eba14d1a0 /usr/local/lib/pkit.so - pkit.so
```

```
#gdb -e /systemd.debug -c /core.83771 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 83771]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 22'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f3eb82b7657 in kill () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb)
```